# my projects functionality works with live server extension only

Tags: javascript, html

I just created my first calculator and it works perfectly on live server, but not directly if opening via HTML file. After placing js, css, img and audio file in separate folder and changing the path in HTML it started working, but the arrow function that serves to delete symbols still not working if opening directly. Any ideas?

```
  <section>
    <p>Olena's <br> calculator</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pic"><img src="files/pic.png" alt="pic"></div>
        <div class="display" id="dis"></div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="button" id="c">C</div>
                <div class="button" id="pro">.</div>
                <div class="button" id="larr">&larr;</div>
                <div class="button" id="sub">/</div>
                <div class="button" id="seven">7</div>
                <div class="button" id="eight">8</div>
                <div class="button" id="nine">9</div>
                <div class="button" id="mul">*</div>
                <div class="button" id="four">4</div>
                <div class="button" id="five">5</div>
                <div class="button" id="six">6</div>
                <div class="button" id="di">-</div>
                <div class="button" id="one">1</div>
                <div class="button" id="two">2</div>
                <div class="button" id="three">3</div>
                <div class="button" id="plus">+</div>
                <div class="button" id="zero">(</div>
                <div class="button" id="dblzero">0</div>
                <div class="button" id="point">)</div>
                <div class="button" id="equal">=</div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>


<audio src="files/mixkit-plastic-bubble-click-1124.wav" id="audio"></audio>

<script src="files/index.js"></script>

buttons.map(but => {
but.addEventListener('click', (key) => {
    console.log(key.target.innerText)
    switch (key.target.innerText) {
        case 'C':  
            display.innerText = ' '
        break
        case '←':
            if (display.innerText) {
            display.innerText = display.innerText.slice(0, -1)
            break
            }
        case '=':
            try{
            display.innerText = eval(display.innerText)
            break
            } catch {
                display.innerText = 'Помилка'
                break
            }
        default:
            display.innerText += key.target.innerText 
    }
})
})

const audio = document.getElementById('audio')

document.onclick = () => audio.play();
```

Comment: there should be following commands at the beginning of JS:
let display = document.getElementById('dis')

let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button'))

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not working"?  Are there any errors or warnings at all on the browser's development console?  When you debug the code in the browser's debugging tools, what specifically happens?

Comment: Hello, no error, It just inputs the <- symbol onto the display as if case '<-' did not exist